# Blender 2.8 malfunctioning

Tags: interface

I just upgrade my blender 2.79 to 2.8, however when upgrades end, my mouse basically lost all its functions. I cannot click the object, cannot select object, all the hotkeys dont work, since like tab to edit mode, g to translate, r to rotate since like that. I cant even do anything with the default cube. The only thing I can do is click all the buttons on the interface. I am wondering what happened. This upgrade really made my day.

Comment: Do you mean all this happened **after** you installed 2.8?

Comment: reset your preferences to defaults and select the Blender 2.7X Keymap if you want your advanced keyboard shortcuts, then add the cool new pie menus to the keymap so you have the best out of 2 worlds

Comment: @HenrikD: It must be more than that as I don't think GRS was changed as well in 2.8. And user Roger has problems with mouse, too.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth I suspect, a corrupted preference is somehow loaded due to some kind of problem while updating to 2.80. The preferences control everything and that would explain it perfectly.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth: yes it all happened after install 2.8. I deleted 2.8 and reinstalled 2.79 everything becomes normal again

Comment: @HenrikD: I did want to try that, but when I open my keymap, there is nothing in there, plus I cant even find an add short cut or edit hotkey button. I redownload 2.79 and deleted 2.8 everything becomes normal again. I do not know how to use my 2.79 setting to 2.8 could you plz explain a bit so that I can take a shot?

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: @HenrikD: win10